# Reauthenticating Firebase user with Google Provider in React

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm using firebase for my web project, and want to allow users to delete their account, which requires [reauth](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#re-authenticate_a_user) according to Firebase. I've been having a lot of trouble getting their `user.reauthenticateAndRetrieveDataWithCredential` to work.

Specifically, I'm not sure how to generate an `AuthCredential` to pass to it using the `GoogleAuthProvider.credential()` [method](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider#.credential), since I don't know how to get a user's ID token or access token.

I've tried `user.getIdToken()` ([here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User#getIdToken)) which gives me an error that the credential is not issued by Google.

Asking the user to sign in again with a popup and then taking the `res.credential` accessToken or idToken works, but then allows them to sign in to a different user at that time which is not what I want.

Any tips on how to get a valid idToken from the currently logged in user for reauthentication?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use `reauthenticateWithPopup`/`reauthenticateWithRedirect`.

```
firebase.auth().currentUser.reauthenticateWithPopup(new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider())
  .then(function(userCredential) {
    // You can now delete the user:
    return firebase.auth().currentUser.delete();
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    // Credential mismatch or some other error.
  });
```

Comment: Please correct me if I'm mistaken, but I don't think this is an existing method of auth? https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth

Comment: Oops, my bad. It is on the user. I updated my answer. The docs are available here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User#reauthenticateWithPopup